# Ksoap2 .NET web service connection

Tags: android, .net, web-services, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pK9rm.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/27Qj0.png

I want to connection web service using ksoap2,I have a working example but how can I integrate my application?

public class WebServiceDemoActivity extends Activity
{

```
  private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/UrunleriListele";
  private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
  private static String METHOD_NAME = "UrunleriListele";
  private static String URL = "http://services.annebebekavm.com/Service1.asmx?WSDL";

  Button btnFar,btnCel,btnClear;
  EditText txtFar,txtCel;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btnFar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFar);

    txtFar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtFar);


    btnFar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v)
              {

              SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);       


              request.addProperty("Fahrenheit",txtFar.getText().toString());


              SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

              envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
              envelope.dotNet = true;

              try {
                    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);


                    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);


                    SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

                    if(result != null)
                    {

                          txtFar.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Response",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
              } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
              }
              }
        });

}
```

}

Comment: I will recomend you to use wsclient++.

Comment: I got it using ksoap2 but now I am try parse my response to webservice

Comment: Or use this http://code.google.com/p/android-ws-client/
this is mutch better.

Answer (score 0):

Please reconsider to use another client

http://code.google.com/p/android-ws-client/

you can create all classe what you need to.
by one application copy libs to your project
with your generate classes

Here is example it look really simple to

```
    Service servis = new Service();
    ServiceSoap soap12 = servis.getServiceSoap12();
    LoginParams inParams = new LoginParams();
    inParams.setLogin("user");
    inParams.setPassword("pass");
    inParams.setStrategy(LoginStrategy.NOHASHPASS); // even enums are supported
    LoginState result = soap.authorize(inParams);

    result.isLogin(); // boolean if is succesfull
```

Comment: Can I make it to the sql query to connect to the client or server?

Comment: I am not shure what you asking for. This is client side.

Comment: Sorry I can't speak english very well :) I want to tell you,Can I connect my database using your code? I hope I can correctly explain my question :)

Comment: Look You have to make Webservice with database connection and send fetched records as collection to client.

CLient(Android) receive data
and some way(KSoap, wsclient++, ...) 
you bind that data to your objects.

So its possible.

Comment: (DB SERVER) <- webservice -> SoapClient(android)

Comment: Yes, I understand.. I am connected web service using ksoap2 and I got the data from web service as a string. http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ss0b8.png
Now how can I parse this datas?

Comment: http://wsclient.neurospeech.com/download/

Download this.

with Win(Flash/Flex) application in package enter url to your wsld

hostname/service.asmx?WSDL
hostname/service.php?WSDL and so on

next you must type desire class name usualy
com.example.ws

the application will generate classes for (java)android
an then you will copy it to your project and copy wsclient lib also.